# What is the Guhya Upanishad mentioned in the Kurma purana?

Tags: puranas, upanishads, devi, agamas, shaktism

In The Kurma Purana, in a discourse between Himavan and Devi (Parvati), Himavan while praising the vibhutis of Devi praises her as follows -

> **सर्वोपनिषदां देवि गुह्योपनिषदुच्यते ।** ईशानश्चासि कल्पानां युगानां कृतमेव च ।१२.२२१
>
> **You are, O Goddess, Guhyopanishad among the Upanisads**, You are Isana Kalpa among the Kalpas, You are Krta Yuga among the Yugas

**~ Kurma Purana I.12.221**

What exactly is this Guhyopanishad? Arthur avalon in his book 'Shakti and Shakta' [mentions it within a list of shakta Upanishads](https://sacred-texts.com/tantra/sas/sas12.htm) . But yet another article as I read [here](https://indiafacts.org/the-monistic-sakta-philosophy-in-the-guhyopanisad/) mentions it as a portion of an Agama named Mahakala samhita, and not an independent text or upanishad.

So the Questions are -

1. Is it an Actual Shakta Upanishad or A portion of an Agama? Or Are there perhaps multiple texts by
   name 'Guhyopanishad'?
2. Depending on whether the answer is yes, or no, Which Guhyopanishad is the Kurma purana verse referring to?
3. Is the Text of the Guhyopanishad accessible online?

Comment: Guhyakālyupaniṣat is a Śākta 'Upaniṣad', and it's available online (check [here](https://archive.org/details/aprakashitupanishads/mode/2up?view=theater)). It's present in the Guhyakāli khaṇḍa of Mahākāla saṁhitā. It's not a part of the Muktikā canon of 108 Upaniṣads. I am not aware of any other Guhyakālyupaniṣat, and I am not sure if Kūrma Purāṇa is really referring to that or not because *Guhya* can be used as an adjective too. There's a Śākta 'Upaniṣad' named 'Guhyaṣoḍhānyāsopaniṣat', (available in the link before), but it's also not part of the Muktikā canon.

Comment: I am using 'Upaniṣad' for these two, because that they're really Upaniṣads or not is a doubtful matter. Traditionally, only the 108 listed in Muktikā Upaniṣad, are accepted as Upaniṣads. There are some (not present in Muktikā), which are also found attached to Veda (such as Praṇavopaniṣat), but I am not sure if the two aforementioned 'Upaniṣads' are present in the surviving Veda śākhās or not. Also, their names as Upaniṣads *might* be more of a glorification of these śāstras, than their being actual Upaniṣads.

Comment: Maybe, But Since the Context is the Glorication of the Vibutis of Devi by singling out a single 'best' entity out of a set of multiple entities, it leads me to conclude that Instead of being used as an adjective it would make more sense for the Term 'Guhyopanisad' too to be used here in the same sense i.e. by singling out a certain upanisad of that name, out of the set of all upanishads. Just my speculation though.

Comment: If that's the case, I think it might very well be Guhyakālyupaniṣat only, however this is most likely not an Upaniṣad *per se* (as in part of Veda).